# What exactly is the difference between update-manager -d and normal apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

The [official recommendation](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/upgrading#Network%20Upgrade%20for%20Ubuntu%20Servers%20%28Recommended%29) of Ubuntu is to use `sudo do-release-upgrade` to do an online upgrade from one version to the next. Historically many of my Debianite friends and myself have simply altered apt's sources.list and run `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

I follow Ubuntu's recommendations, but I've always wondered what the magic difference between these two processes is. What, *exactly*, does `do-release-upgrade` do, on say an upgrade from 9.04 to 9.10? (Examples from other releases welcome.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do-release-upgrade` is a Python script and it makes use of other Python files in `/usr/share/pyshared/DistUpgrade`. If you look at those, you'll get an idea what it's doing.

Comment: I checked, and unlike I was expecting, it's fairly self-documenting. There's a bundle of python scripts, and they do things like fix Xorg configs and changes the desktop theme for users. About the only relevant server thing I found was an apt autoinst fixup.